# Links between biases and personality?

Tags: bias

I was thinking of how [a lot of people are biased against overweight people](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/why-are-people-biased-against-overweight-people/13243#13243).
.

One of the answers considers how we tend to "take part" with those that remind us of ourselves, and we are biased against those who seem different from us.
This should imply that a person who is biased against overweight people is a person who considers him/herself "not one of the overweight people".
This further implies that the biases a person has, says something about his/her identity.

- Is there any research on what characterizes people who are biased against any specific group of people?
- Is there any kind of research on what characterizes people prone to any specific bias?